# What is the difference between dict, collections.defaultdict, collections.OrderedDict, collectinos.UserDict?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary, defaultdict

What is the difference between dict, collections.defaultdict, collections.OrderedDict, collectinos.UserDict?

Please help me with examples.

Comment: You should start by reading the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html Then ask a specific question if it is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

They're basically all dictionnary with different flavor.  You can use them as you would with dictionary.

- dict is the "normal" one which do {key:value} without ordering or memory
- defaultdict adds the "default" value when a key is called if the key is missing (adding the value at the same time).
- OrderedDict remember the order in which the **keys** have been added.

Unfortunatly, I don't know about the last one, but here is the [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict)

the UserDict.data would be what act as the normal dict, but I don't know which use case would be interested in this...

Let me know if this clarify what you wanted to know.  I suggest you see ["super considered super!" by Raymond hettinger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) if you want to see something cool to do with this.

Comment: Looking for answers like these. Appreciate your answer. Please add if you have any other details.

Comment: I didn't go into detail, but if you've liked the answer, please flag it for other people :)

Comment: Ok. I know details about them. But, I want to know why do we have these many dicts and what is inner reason behind having those many.

Comment: Oh I see, let me try to rephrase what I meant.  Let's say you want to keep the order of the dict, but still want to apply it to something that consumes dicts (i.e. a function that sends message to the other end of a connection, but you want to send them in the order they are being populated in your dictionary and not the random default order).  The ordered dict can easely replace a normal one, yet the function was developped with a normal one in mind.  so go and see dependency injection in super considered super.  there is an example of exactly this with dict :).